# How to use cwac2 camera with custom layout

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'd like to use [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2) library, as it seems to be the best one out there (i've used the first version cwac camera some time ago) but I'd like to use my own implementation of `CameraActivity`. Have a custom layout surrounding the preview.

What I mean by this is I'd like to have the camera preview in a frame in the screen and have my own custom controls on the layout, the ones that switch the camera (FFC, RFC) and also the btn to take a picture.

I've created a class which extends `CameraActivity` but I can't seem to figure out how to get the `CameraFragment` and add it to my own layout and use it like that.

Can anyone offer a helping hand? I'm kinda stuck ...

P.S. an idea that came to me would be to download the library offline (not using gradle dependencies) and customize it to my needs, but I'm 99% positive it can be done in a more simpler way, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: "I'd like to use my own implementation of CameraActivity. Have a custom layout surrounding the preview" -- that is not supported by the library. You are welcome to try to hack something together, as others have, but that's not something that I am aiming to support. "but I'm 99% positive it can be done in a more simpler way" -- I am 99% positive that it cannot be done in a simpler way.

Comment: Shucks. Well ok then... Thanks a bunch ... Also, nice job with the first cwac library, it really helped a lot with a bunch of past projects :) Thanks again ...